# java drawstring arraylist

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, paint

If I am using the drawString(String, Int, Int) command in java. How can I store / call different graphics that have been stored in an ArrayList?

So, for example,

```
ArrayList<what type will this be???> list = new ArrayList;
int pos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    g.get(i).drawString("hello", 50, 50 + pos);
    pos += 20;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
list.get(i).drawString("hello", 50, 50 + pos);
```

If you want to store different objects/shapes in `ArrayList<T>`, the T has to be a superclass defining `drawString()`. Otherwise this code won't compile.

Comment: If i is lets say an integer and I iterate from 0 - 10 and create 10 strings "hello" in different positions, if I then call list.get(2).drawString("hello", 100, 100); Will that only move one of the strings that was referenced at list position 2?

Answer (score 0):

I used this for a program:

```
ArrayList<String[]> StringsToDraw = new ArrayList<String[]>(); 

StringsToDraw.add(new String[] {"Hello","20","35"}); 
StringsToDraw.add(new String[] {"World","100","100"}); 

@Override 
public void paint(Graphics g){
  for(String[] printMe : StringsToDraw){ 
    drawString(g, printMe[0], printMe[1], printMe[2]) 
  } 
} 

public void drawString(Graphics gr, String text, String xString, String yString){ 
    int x = Integer.parseInt(xString); 
    int y = Integer.parseInt(yString); 
    gr.drawString(text, x, y); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem doing that?

```
    List<Graphics2D> list = new ArrayList<Graphics2D>();
    int pos = 0;
    for (Graphics2D g : list) {
        g.drawString("hello", 50, 50 + pos);
        pos += 20;
    }
```

and you could better use **for-each** and define your **list** object using an interface *List*.